Configure a Git branch to always force push?
I'm writing a Git plugin that only works when git push is passed the --force flag. I could use a pre-push hook to bail with an error message if the --force flag isn't given, but I'd like to have better UX than that.
Is it possible to configure Git to always force-push implicitly (either for a specific configured branch or for all branches)?

If you are always using force push, you are no longer using git. You might want to reconsider your design.

It might be better to just not activate your plugin if --force is not provided. It would be very dangerous to make --force implicit even if it were possible.

It doesn't seem that there is such an option: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config And it is a good thing, you really don't want to use it, not in a regular workflow anyway

This is a perfectly fine use-case that git(1) happens to not support (it seems). git(1) is a toolkit more than it is an opinionated VCS.

@Guildenstern, and I can install a screw with a hammer - but it's no longer a screw at that point, just a bad nail.  git push --force is fine on a local branch or when you are the only user of a branch, but it is antisocial and antithetical to distributed vcs otherwise.  @joshlf's mention of "for all branches" implies this is not limited in use, and would thus not represent what most people think of when the word "git" is said.

Based on @joshlf's post history, I suspect this relates to github pages.  While the question is understandable in that context, I'd still say putting it in git instead of a more dedicated wrapper with it's own semantics is asking for trouble.  Is there a technical difference? No.  Is there a semantic difference?  I'd argue there is.

@Mitch The metaphor doesn’t make sense. Force-pushing is just as much part of the toolkit as anything else. But maybe we should take it to (Git) chat

It's not public (yet), but I have a project attempting to emulate Gerrit's stacked PRs in GitHub. So you always want to force push because the intended workflow is to overwrite the feature branch with your current copy. You can see an example of what it produces here.

Interesting. To my naive mind I think it would make more sense to use tags with an incrementing integer at the end. Then you know that the latest version is the one with the highest number and you still have all the force pushes easily available.

Each commit gets put on its own auto-generated branch. There's one "real" branch (that the user sees) and N auto-generated branches (one per commit). This lets us emulate "one PR per commit". You can see an example of its output here - the PR message is auto-generated by the tool. Note the branch names.
I'd like to support per-PR history by having each auto-gen'd branch have its own synthesized history, but I haven't gotten that working yet.
Feel free to drop me a line if you'd like to see the code - hello@joshlf.com.
